# Target only the first direct child not working despite :nth-child(1)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So basically I have this markup, which is a very simplified output of a component I'm working on.

On the CSS, I just want to style (apply gray color) the first direct child, but it's also applying the style to the indirect nested children despite adding `nth-child(1)`. Why is this? And how can I fix this?

```css
.row {
margin: 5px 0;
}

.row.row-selected{ border-left: 1px solid red; }

.row.row-selected .row-data:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-selected">
  <div class="row-data">Foo1</div>
 
  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20px">
    <div class="row-data">Foo1Child1</div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20px">
    <div class="row-data">Foo1Child2</div>
  </div>
 
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="row-data">Foo2</div>
 
  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20px">
    <div class="row-data">Foo2Child1</div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20px">
    <div class="row-data">Foo2Child2</div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: try with direct child selector .row.row-selected > .row-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is applying to all nested elements because you are using a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) (a space character) between selectors:

```
.row.row-selected .row-data:nth-child(1) { }
```

This combinator targets all specified descendants (not just children) of the first selector.

Plus, your targeted element (`.row-data`) is, in fact, the first child (`:nth-child(1)`) of a parent element in all cases.

Instead, use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) (`>`), which targets only the children of an element.

```css
.row.row-selected > div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.row.row-selected {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-selected">
  <div class="row-data">Foo1</div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20px">
    <div class="row-data">Foo1Child1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20px">
    <div class="row-data">Foo1Child2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="row-data">Foo2</div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20px">
    <div class="row-data">Foo2Child1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20px">
    <div class="row-data">Foo2Child2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the parent/child selector?

```
.row.row-selected > .row-data {
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
```

This makes sure that only direct child of `.row.row-selected` with a class of `.row-data` is selected.